# S0 Low Power Idle message WM_POWERBROADCAST not received Windows 10 C++

Tags: c++, windows, desktop

I have an application that does receive the WM_POWERBROADCAST message and works fine on older systems (Use S3 sleep state).  I have a new computer, Windows 10, that uses the S0 Low Power Idle mode.  From reading the MSDN documentation, it sounds like the Desktop Activity Moderator (DAM) should be sending my Win32 application that message before going into sleep mode.  I am not seeing it.

I have looked at the **powercfg** utility and some of the reports, but I don't see anything helpful.

I am wondering if I am not either properly entering this sleep mode, or I need to be done something else to be notified of the power state change.  What utility can I use to see what is happening on this new computer?  Should I be doing something else instead of the WM_POWERBROADCAST method to detect this power state change on this new computer?  Thanks!